# c#: Check uploaded files and continue uploading

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp

Im using DotNetZip for making zip files and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class) for uploading to ftp and both working perfectly.

I want to check ftp server for files those already been uploaded in case of losing connection to server. then continue the uploading process (not from the start) when connection established again.

Here is my code with comments:

```
public void DoResume(string output,string address, string username,string password)
    {
        // create instance of uploading method
        var ftpClient = new ftp(address, username, password);
        // get the location of all files in output directory
        // output is the location of zip files
        var filesAddress = Directory.GetFiles(output);
        // get location of all files in output directory
        // var filesName = Directory.GetFiles(output).select(Path.GetDileName).ToArray();
        // get name of uploaded files
        var getuploadedfiles = ftpClient.directoryListSimple("/");
        // Upload Files
        foreach (var serverfile in getuploadedfiles)
        {
            foreach (var fadddress in filesAddress)
            {
                var outputfile = Path.GetFileName(fadddress);
                if (serverfile != outputfile)
                {
                    // save *fadddress* file as *outputfile* in server 
                    ftpClient.upload(outputfile, fadddress);
                }

            }
        }
```

---

*This is what the code suppose to do:* checking is the file is already been uploaded, if true then skip to next file and check again,if not uploaded then do the upload for this file.

*This is what will happen:* it will upload all files again except the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will check the server, if some files have not been uploaded before, it will continue uploading:

```
public void DoResume(string output,string address, string username,string password)
    {
        var ftpClient = new ftp(address, username, password);
        // Get the name of all files in output directory
        var localfiles = Directory.GetFiles(output).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
        /* Get names of uploaded files  */
        var getuploadedfiles = ftpClient.directoryListSimple("/");
        // Get files those are not uploaded
        var diff = localfiles.Except(getuploadedfiles);
        /* Upload Files */
        foreach (var dif in diff)
        {
            foreach (var file in localfiles)
            {
                if (dif != file) continue;
                var filetoupload = $"{output}{dif}";
                ftpClient.upload(file, filetoupload);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} been uploaded", filetoupload);           
            }
        }
    }
```